# align list items with the same width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a simple menu bar using the `ul` tag,which has 4 links.
The `ul` width is 100% of the screen width,so according to this every `li` should be 25%.

i've tried doing this,but the last list item just falls down to the next line..
However if i will use `width:23%` for each li,it would look good.
But im very curious why this is happening,why 25% is not good enough?

This is my pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKryKW
I would appreciate any help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. You have spaces in your html. This is always a problem with inline block elements. Remove them and the spaces in your result go away. See this explanation: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

http://codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/YWKRVQ

```
<ul>
  <li><a> first</a></li><li><a> second</a></li><li><a> third</a></li><li><a> fourth</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of: display: inline-block will alway leave a few pixels between the block, so it would alway be more than 100%. You're also adding 22px padding, making the width: 25% + 22px +22px (left and right) to avoid this use `box-sizing: border-box;`

```
li {
  font-size:25px;
  padding: 22px;
  width:25%;
  text-align:center;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wietsedevries/kmzym3xL/

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to remove `padding right and left` from `lis` , then you need also to add `font-size:0` to `ul` to make it ignore spacing between `lis`

```css
*{
  
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  
   
}
ul
{
  
  height:70px;
  background-color:#e1973d;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:100%;
  font-size:0;
}
li
{
 font-size:25px;
   padding: 22px 0;
  width:25%;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a> first</a> </li>
 <li><a> second</a> </li>
   <li><a> third</a> </li>
     <li><a> fourth</a> </li>
</ul>
```